# the fillter springSecurityFilterChain make the mvc spring can not target resource

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, legacy-app

I want to add some security to my spring mvc project on spring suite tool 
I follow the Blog Post [here the link](https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/) here step by step and every thing go ok and the code run fine until I add springSecurityFilterChain fillter then the code can not run no error BUt when I run the project the web browser show mssage **The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.**

**My Pom.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.journaldev.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringMVCHibernate</artifactId>
    <name>SpringMVCHibernate</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.1.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
        <springsecurity.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <!-- <version>1.5.6</version> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
           <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

**My web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
  </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**My servlete_context.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans 
     xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />

    </beans:bean>


       <security:http auto-config="true" >
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/"     access="hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/home" access="hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')" />
        <security:form-login  login-page="/login" 
                     username-parameter="ssoId" 
                     password-parameter="password" 
                     authentication-failure-url="/Access_Denied" /><!-- enable csrf protection --> <security:csrf/> 
    </security:http>

    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

    <security:authentication-manager >
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="bill"  password="abc123"  authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                <security:user name="admin" password="root123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <security:user name="dba"   password="root123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_DBA" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

     <context:component-scan base-package="com.websystique.springsecurity" /> 


</beans:beans>
```

**My controller :**

```
package com.websystique.springsecurity;

import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.websystique.springsecurity.model.User;
import com.websystique.springsecurity.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @Autowired
    UserService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/list" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listAllUsers(ModelMap model) {

        List<User> users = service.findAllUsers();
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        return "allusers";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/edit-user-{id}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editUser(@PathVariable int id, ModelMap model) {
        User user  = service.findById(id);
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("edit", true);
        return "registration";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/edit-user-{id}" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateUser(User user, ModelMap model, @PathVariable int id) {
        service.updateUser(user);
        model.addAttribute("success", "User " + user.getFirstName()  + " updated successfully");
        return "success";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/delete-user-{id}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable int id) {
        service.deleteUser(id);
        return "redirect:/list";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Access_Denied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String accessDeniedPage(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
        return "accessDenied";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage() {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null){    
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
        }
        return "redirect:/login?logout";
    }

    private String getPrincipal(){
        String userName = null;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            userName = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            userName = principal.toString();
        }
        return userName;
    }

}
```

**My login.jse:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Login page</title>
        <link href="<c:url value='/static/css/bootstrap.css' />"  rel="stylesheet"></link>
        <link href="<c:url value='/static/css/app.css' />" rel="stylesheet"></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="mainWrapper">
            <div class="login-container">
                <div class="login-card">
                    <div class="login-form">
                        <c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login" />
                        <form action="${loginUrl}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

                            <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <p>Invalid username and password.</p>
                                </div>
                            </c:if>
                            <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
                                <div class="alert alert-success">
                                    <p>You have been logged out successfully.</p>
                                </div>
                            </c:if>
                            <div class="input-group input-sm">
                                <label class="input-group-addon" for="username"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="ssoId" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group input-sm">
                                <label class="input-group-addon" for="password"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></label> 
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"  value="${_csrf.token}" />

                            <div class="form-actions">
                                <input type="submit"
                                    class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-default" value="Log in">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

[image: here the picture show of the structer of my code]

so what wrong ? why the login.jsp not found after I add the fillter any help ?

Comment: I usually configure `spring-security` stuff in `spring`'s root context instead of `DispatcherServlet`'s servlet context. You could give it a try.

Comment: @jlumietu thank you verey much you save my life , I configure spring-security stuff in spring's root context instead of DispatcherServlet's servlet context and it work like charm